# HTTP Post to login to a website with timestamp, token, username and password

Tags: http

From a script I want to login to a website.
For that I searched the source for the POST request. The post request to login the website has the data "username", "passwort", "timestamp" and "token".
However when I copy the timestamp and token and paste the post request to my browsers address bar with my username and password like this:

```
https://example.com/action/login?__elgg_token=905adbf0c0111fef78a8344c38c8f2a8&__elgg_ts=1461577445&username=foo&password=bar
```

the login is unsuccessful.
Do I need a different token and timestamp?

This is from the source:

```
action="https://example.com/action/login" method="post" > 

<input type="hidden"  name="__elgg_token"  value="905adbf0c0111fef78a8344c38c8f2a8" />

<input type="hidden"  name="__elgg_ts"  value="1461577445" />

<input type="text"   name="username"  value="" class="form-control login-textarea form-control" />

<input type="password"   name="password"  value="" class="form-control login-textarea" />
```

Comment: There's a difference between POST and GET. Passing parameters in the URL will result in a GET. Any server is free to treat a GET with parameters differently from the POST it expects.

Comment: Also, that tag [post] is for the Power On Self Test. Not the HTTP varient.

Answer (score 0):

> **when I copy the timestamp and token and paste [it into a URL in a browser's address bar] ... the login is unsuccessful**

AFAIK the address bar in common web-browsers causes the browser to issue a HTTP GET request, not a HTTP POST request.

As [Class Stacker](https://superuser.com/users/360870/class-stacker) commented. You cannot assume that a POST request can be transformed into an equivalent GET request that will be recognised by the server.

> **From a script I want to login to a website [which expects an HTTP POST request]**

If your are using a conventional command-line scripting language there are several tools you can use to issue a POST request.

From a shell script, you can use tools like Wget or cURL to issue POST requests and capture any resulting session cookies etc.

Scripts written using other scripting languages or more general purpose languages (Perl, Ruby, Python etc) usually have standard libraries that cater for issuing POST and GET requests and managing cookies etc.

Example from [Wget man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#HTTP-Options)

```
# Log in to the server.  This can be done only once.
wget --save-cookies cookies.txt \
     --post-data 'user=foo&password=bar' \
     http://server.com/auth.php

# Now grab the page or pages we care about.
wget --load-cookies cookies.txt \
     -p http://server.com/interesting/article.php
```

Other examples are not hard to find

- [How can I login to a website with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2910221/477035)
- [Perl Script for logging into a website](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27826290/477035)